# Server does not receive what I send over TCP

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, sockets, tcp

I am currently writing a client-server app for iOS. Client is Objective-C/CocoaTouch and server backend is written in C++. Right now I am struggling with the TCP communications -- sending over a file to the server, to be specific.

Every other packet send/receive works, but for this packet the server seems to receive "bad" data. Both the server and the client are little endian, so endianness is not the problem.

Here's the sender code:

```
- (void) sendGameUpdateWithFile:(NSString*)filePath gameID:(NSInteger)gameID {
    NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    fileheadPacket head;

    head.msgtype = 0x12;
    strncpy(head.data1, [myUsername cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], [myUsername length]);
    head.data1[[myUsername length]] = '\0';
    int followingPackets = 1;
    if([data length] % 1024 == 0){
        if([data length] > 1024){
            followingPackets = (int)[data length]/1024;
        }
    } else {
        followingPackets = (int)([data length]/1024)+1;
    }
    head.following = followingPackets;
    head.fileid = (int)gameID;
    head.size = sizeof(fileheadPacket);

    [mySock writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:&head length:sizeof(fileheadPacket)] withTimeout:-1 tag:8];

    NSRange thisRange;
    thisRange.length = 1024;

    for(int i = 0; i < followingPackets; i++){
        thisRange.location = i*1024;

        if(thisRange.location + thisRange.length > [data length]){
            thisRange.length = [data length] - thisRange.location;
        }

        filePacket tmp;
        tmp.extra = (int)thisRange.length;
        tmp.msgtype = 0x13;
        tmp.size = sizeof(filePacket);
        tmp.following = (int)gameID;
        [data getBytes:tmp.fileBuffer range:thisRange];

        [mySock writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:&tmp length:sizeof(filePacket)] withTimeout:-1 tag:8];

        NSLog(@"Wrote packet of type 0x%02x, size %d", tmp.msgtype, tmp.size);
    }
}
```

Pardon the messiness of that code, it's still in early development and will be improved.

Here's the receiver's code:

```
std::vector<filePacket> PacketInterpreter::readPacket(filePacket* inPacket, int FD){
    //The returned vector contains stuff to return to the socket. If it's empty, there's nothing to return (and thus, the client on that FD shouldn't be listening)

    packetsToSend.clear();
    packetsToSend.reserve(1024);

    std::cout << "Received a packet of type " << inPacket->msgtype << " with size " << inPacket->size << std::endl;

    switch (inPacket->msgtype){
        case 0x12:
        {
            fileheadPacket* ptr = (fileheadPacket*) inPacket;
            assembleFile(ptr->following, ptr->fileid);
            break;
        }
        case 0x13:
            concatFilePart(inPacket->extra, inPacket->following, inPacket->fileBuffer);
            break;
    }

    return packetsToSend;

}

void PacketInterpreter::assembleFile(int following, int gameID){
    std::cout << "assembleFile with following: " << following << " and gameid " << gameID << std::endl;
    char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(following+1)*1024);
    inAssembly.insert(std::make_pair(gameID, s));
    inAssemblyCountdown.insert(std::make_pair(gameID, following+1));
    inAssemblyCountup.insert(std::make_pair(gameID, 0));
}

void PacketInterpreter::concatFilePart(int readLen, int gameID, unsigned char* data){

    for(int i = 0; i < readLen; i++){
        inAssembly[gameID][inAssemblyCountup[gameID]] = data[i];
        inAssemblyCountup[gameID]++;
    }

    inAssemblyCountdown[gameID]--;
    if(readLen != 1024 || inAssemblyCountdown[gameID] == 0){
        makeFile(gameID, inAssembly[gameID]);
        delete inAssembly[gameID];
        inAssembly.erase(gameID);
        inAssemblyCountdown.erase(gameID);

    }
}

void PacketInterpreter::makeFile(int gameID, char* buffer){
    std::string rmgameIDdir = ("rm -r " + std::to_string(gameID));
    system(rmgameIDdir.c_str());
    std::string gameIDdir = "mkdir " + std::to_string(gameID);
    std::string constructedPath = std::to_string(gameID);
    constructedPath += "/";

    std::system(gameIDdir.c_str());
    std::cout << gameIDdir.c_str() << std::endl;

    std::ofstream thisFile;
    thisFile.open(constructedPath+"sound.caf");

    std::cout << "opened " << constructedPath+"sound.caf" << " is open? " << thisFile.is_open() << std::endl;


    std::string temp = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < inAssemblyCountup[gameID]; i++){
        thisFile << std::hex << buffer[i];
    }
    thisFile.close();

    std::cout << "File assembled at " << constructedPath << "sound.caf" << std::endl;
}

void PacketInterpreter::assembleFile(int following, int gameID){
    std::cout << "assembleFile with following: " << following << " and gameid " << gameID << std::endl;
    char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(following+1)*1024);
    inAssembly.insert(std::make_pair(gameID, s));
    inAssemblyCountdown.insert(std::make_pair(gameID, following+1));
    inAssemblyCountup.insert(std::make_pair(gameID, 0));
}

void PacketInterpreter::concatFilePart(int readLen, int gameID, unsigned char* data){

    for(int i = 0; i < readLen; i++){
        inAssembly[gameID][inAssemblyCountup[gameID]] = data[i];
        inAssemblyCountup[gameID]++;
    }

    inAssemblyCountdown[gameID]--;
    if(readLen != 1024 || inAssemblyCountdown[gameID] == 0){
        makeFile(gameID, inAssembly[gameID]);
        delete inAssembly[gameID];
        inAssembly.erase(gameID);
        inAssemblyCountdown.erase(gameID);

    }
}
```

The structs I use on both sides of the connection look like this:

```
//Packet used for small stuff
typedef struct small_packet {
    int msgtype;
    int size;
    int extra;
    int following;
    char data1[64];
    char data2[64];
} packet;

//Packet used for files
typedef struct file_packet {
    int msgtype; //For partial file packet this should be 0x02
    int size;
    int extra;
    int following;
    char data1[64];
    unsigned char fileBuffer[1024];
} filePacket;

//Used for file headers
typedef struct filehead_packet {
    int msgtype;
    int size;
    int extra;
    int following;
    char data1[64];
    int fileid;
    char rest[60];
} fileheadPacket;
```

I know for certain that the structs are packed the same way on both units, because all the other messages use the same packets and they work as they should. When I attempt to send a file from client->server, this is a typical log:

```
Received a packet of type 18 with size 144
assembleFile with following: 367 and gameid 109
Received a packet of type 19 with size 1104
Received a packet of type 19 with size 1104
Received a packet of type 19 with size 1104
Received a packet of type 19 with size 1104
Checking for new games
Received a packet of type 0 with size 0
Received a packet of type -262149 with size -196612
Received a packet of type -131075 with size -196612
Received a packet of type -1 with size -1
Received a packet of type 327685 with size 327685
Received a packet of type 131074 with size 196611
Received a packet of type 65537 with size 65537
Received a packet of type -65538 with size -65538
Received a packet of type 131074 with size 196611
Received a packet of type 196611 with size 65537
Received a packet of type 131074 with size 196611
Received a packet of type 393222 with size 196611
Received a packet of type 0 with size 0
... many packets which make no sense, although the total number of packets is correct (367 in this case) ...
Received a packet of type -196612 with size -196612
Received a packet of type 131074 with size 131074
Received a packet of type 65537 with size 131074
Received a packet of type -196612 with size -196612
Received a packet of type 0 with size 65537
Received a packet of type -393223 with size -327686
Received a packet of type 131074 with size 131074
Received a packet of type 393222 with size 393222
Received a packet of type 0 with size 0
Received a packet of type 19 with size 1104
Received a packet of type 19 with size 1104
Received a packet of type 19 with size 1104
mkdir 109
opened 109/sound.caf is open? 1
File assembled at 109/sound.caf
```

It just drives me mad because I have no clue what's wrong. Let me know if you need more code samples (such as the select()-block in main() which sends and receives packets. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just in case you are writing &s,sizeof(s) structs directly to the wire, note that the layout and size of them may not be the same on both ends, as well as the endianess.

Comment: As I point out in my question, the endianness of both ends is the same, and the packing is the same (I have checked the ASM created by the compilers at both ends, and they match).

Answer (score -2):

I have actually found out what's wrong here. The server reads quicker than the iPhone sends its packets, which means only the first half or so of the packets transfered from the iPhone has reached the end of the line at the server's filedescriptor when the server attempts to read a full sizeof(filePacket).

Since both machines are little endian, the "tail" of the packet is read first by the server, and in this case, the meta information contained in each packet is stored "at the end" of the data currently available at the file descriptor. As we attempt to read 1140 bytes and only say... half of it has actually arrived, the metadata gets random values from inside the fileBuffer field of the packet.

I quickfixed the problem by "slowing down" the reading on the server side, but I think I will have to reduce the total size of the filePacket structs in order to make it function properly without being slowed programmatically.

So what did I learn today? Don't send too large packets over TCP and expect the server to read it all in one chunk. 1K is way too much to send at once.

Comment: I think you should have learned more than that.  The proper fix is to sit in a loop and wait until you receive everything you expect (which can be a fixed-known-size or transmitted as part of the header).  This is standard practice.  Your fix is also broken.

Comment: And I will downvote it to avoid others copying your "answer".

Comment: You MUST implement a proper protocol, as instructed by @trojanfoe and others.  If you do not, the inherent borkness of your design will emerge again.